# Mavericks - USB to HDMI Monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos

I'd like to update to Mavericks on my "mid 2012" MBP, but am worried about my monitor setup. I have two [Samsung S22C300 Monitors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C18YQ86) attached to my computer, one via a thunderbolt to HDMI adapter, and the other through a [Cable Matters USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter](http://www.cablematters.com/cs-Downloads.aspx) which has drivers only updated to Snow Leopard, but they work ok on Mountain Lion (with a little monitor lag, but I've gotten used to that).

Has anyone had an issues with their "third" monitor with the new MacOS? More specifically, any issues with connecting monitors to USB with the *Cable Matters* adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing that I have run into personally but I just ran across this:

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/os-x-mavericks-breaks-multi-monitor-setups-with-some-usb-displays/

Which indicates major issues witht he author's USB monitor (DisplayLink) so I would not upgrade untill you are either sure you have updated drivers or can do without your second monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I have that Cable Matters USB to HDMI adapter and it does not work with Mavericks.  I also have a Kensington USB to DVI and it does not work with Mavericks either.

Comment: Wow, that's really a bummer. Have you heard of any USB-to-HDMI adapters that do?

Answer (score 1):

I have the CM USB3->hdmi adapter as well.  It works, but randomly it freezes up, goes black, then comes back up over the course of about 3-5 seconds.  The entire USB bus seems to be frozen during that time as well since I can't type or use my mouse.